# SSZipArchive: Get filename of file being moved in one of the delegate methods (e.g zipArchiveShouldUnzipFileAtIndex)

Tags: ios, swift, ssziparchive

I have a zip file that I'm going to unzip using `SSZipArchive`. But I don't want to unzip every file in the zip. I need only some of the file based on condition.

I know the delegate method of `SSZipArchive`, i.e `zipArchiveShouldUnzipFileAtIndex(fileIndex:, totalFiles:, archivePath:, fileInfo:)` will be helpful.

But how can I get the name of the file being unzipped (being moved from zip file to the unzip location), so that I can return `true` or `false` using the condition ?

Comment: I have changed the library files and now I'm getting 'filename'. If anyone needs that code, let me know.

Comment: Can you give me the code how you are saving contents to zip file and get the zip file?Please check my question if you can help me it will be great. http://stackoverflow.com/q/43263927/1842304

Comment: @reetu, Your question is very different from my question. Your question is about zipping the files, where as my question is about unzipping file selectively.